# QGIS dialogs change size on multi monitor setup

Tags: qgis

I've been using QGIS for a number of years on a single monitor setup. I have now added a second monitor and the various dialog boxes change size each time I open them up. Is there a way of stopping this? I'm using 3.22

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of before and after?  I'm wondering if it's just a difference in the monitor resolution?

Answer (score 1):

I have replicated this issue on my own computer.  I have issued a bug report here.
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/46102
After some testing I have narrowed it down to different scaling on the two monitors.  One is set to 125% while the other is set to 100%. QGIS, for certain dialog boxes, uses the 125% scaling even though it is on the 100% scaled monitor.

Please add your comments to the bug report as well.

Comment: I my case the dialog boxed seemed the 'grow' on each opening. Exporting a print layout to PDF - I exported 6 maps and by the 3rd I had to resize the dialog to see the OK button. The Composer screen was on my 2nd, slightly larger, monitor and the main QGIS window was on my laptop screen. The dialog appears on the laptop screen. The second monitor is, I think, a 17" screen and the laptop 15".